# Extract last name, first name and suffix into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I was wondering if someone could provide me an easy way to extract the names into different columns as below. There is a comma after the Last Name and space between First Name, Middle Initial, and Suffix. Greatly appreciate it.

**Stored Data:**

```
Name
Walker,James M JR
Smith,Jack P
Smith,Whitney
```

**Required result:**

```
LastName   FirstName   Suffix
Walker     James       JR
Smith      Jack
Smith      Whitney
```

**Tried Code:**

```
select top 5 Name,
LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) - 1) AS LastName,
right(Name, len(Name) - CHARINDEX(',', Name)) as FirstName
```

Just having problem with separating First Name from Middle Initial and Suffix. Then getting Suffix from the last space from the right.

Comment: Take a look at the string functions available. A combination of `substring` and `charindex` should be what you need.

Comment: select top 5 Name,
LEFT(Name, CHARINDEX(',', Name) - 1) AS lastname,
right(Name, len(Name) - CHARINDEX(',', Name)) as firstname.....I am having just separating firstname and suffix now.

Comment: From your sample data, how can you tell that `P` is a middle initial and not a Suffix? (Not considering domain knowledge as the computer hasn't any)

Comment: It seems our users enter lastname then comma then firstname then space MI then space suffix. So may be first space after firstname gets to MI and second space will get to suffix.

Comment: Or, let's just get Lastname and Firstname to make it easy. I think suffix might be option. So how can I remove everything after firstname in my code I updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should store these parts of the name in separate columns (first normal form) to avoid such parsing.

You can put all the logic into one huge call of nested functions, but it is quite handy to separate them into single calls using `CROSS APPLY`.

The parsing is straight-forward:

- find position of comma
- split the string into part before comma (`LastName`) and part `AfterComma`
- find position of first space in the second part `AfterComma`
- split the string into two parts again - this gives `FirstName` and the rest (`AfterSpace`)
- find position of space in `AfterSpace`
- split the string into two parts again - this gives `Initial` and `Suffix`.

The query also checks results of `CHARINDEX` - it returns 0 if the string is not found.

Obviously, if the string value is not in the expected format, you'll get incorrect result.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Name varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO @T (Name) VALUES
('Walker'),
('Walker,James M JR'),
('Smith,Jack P'),
('Smith,Whitney');

SELECT
    Name
    ,LastName
    ,AfterComma
    ,FirstName
    ,AfterSpace
    ,MidInitial
    ,Suffix
FROM
    @T
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', Name) AS CommaPosition) AS CA_CP
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CommaPosition > 0 THEN 
        LEFT(Name, CommaPosition - 1) ELSE Name END AS LastName) AS CA_LN
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CommaPosition > 0 THEN 
        SUBSTRING(Name, CommaPosition + 1, 8000) ELSE '' END AS AfterComma) AS CA_AC

    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', AfterComma) AS SpacePosition) AS CA_SP
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SpacePosition > 0 THEN 
        LEFT(AfterComma, SpacePosition - 1) ELSE AfterComma END AS FirstName) AS CA_FN
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN SpacePosition > 0 THEN 
        SUBSTRING(AfterComma, SpacePosition + 1, 8000) ELSE '' END AS AfterSpace) AS CA_AS

    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', AfterSpace) AS Space2Position) AS CA_S2P
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN Space2Position > 0 THEN 
        LEFT(AfterSpace, Space2Position - 1) ELSE AfterSpace END AS MidInitial) AS CA_MI
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN Space2Position > 0 THEN 
        SUBSTRING(AfterSpace, Space2Position + 1, 8000) ELSE '' END AS Suffix) AS CA_S
```

**result**

```
Name                 LastName    AfterComma    FirstName    AfterSpace  MidInitial  Suffix
Walker               Walker
Walker,James M JR    Walker      James M JR    James        M JR        M           JR
Smith,Jack P         Smith       Jack P        Jack         P           P
Smith,Whitney        Smith       Whitney       Whitney
```

Comment: Oh wow! I agree with the normalization. I wonder why our vendor combines the name this way. Such a pain.